# ERROR: File google-services.json is missing. (Since com.google.gms:google-services updated from 4.2.0 to 4.3.0)

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, google-play-services

Since I updated `com.google.gms:google-services` from version 4.2.0 to 4.3.0 in my top level build.gradle, I cannot compile my project any more because I have the error :

> "File google-services.json is missing"

My `google-services.json` are in :

- `/My/personnal/project/app/src/ProductFlavors/BuildTypes`

(for example)

- `/My/personnal/project/app/src/AT/debug`
- `/My/personnal/project/app/src/DE/debug`
- `/My/personnal/project/app/src/AT/release (...)`

**When my version is 4.2.0, I have no issue but in 4.3.0 I have the error** and the Searched Location is: 
/My/personnal/project/app/google-services.json

not working

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.3.0'
    }
```

working

```
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.4.2'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'
    }
```

**EDIT 1**

Looks like it has been resolved with version 4.3.1

**EDIT 2**

Looks like issue is back on version 4.3.2 :(

**EDIT 3**

Issue still there with 4.3.3 :(

Comment: this is not how localization works on Android ...

Comment: @MartinZeitler you are right... after looking at the [doc](https://developers.google.com/android/guides/google-services-plugin) I found that it should be /My/personnal/project/app/src/BuildType/ProductFlavor. But trying this, when I try yo build my project I have the errror : File google-services.json is missing. Searched Location: /My/personnal/project/app/src/ProductFlavor/BuildType/google-services.json ; /My/personnal/project/app/google-services.json. (even with 4.2.0 version)
How should it be ?

Comment: Hi @RomainBarbier, did you find a solution for this. I got the exact same issue...
Is it not enough to just paste 1 google-services.json file in the 'app' module root folder?

Comment: hi @Allinone51 nope I did not... I am still on version 4.3.1... and my files are in folders : /My/personnal/project/app/src/ProductFlavors/BuildTypes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is already an open issue on github based on this

https://github.com/google/play-services-plugins/issues/91

The problem is google-services plugin ignores the build variant if it starts with a capital letter.

If you refactor the build variant names to camelCase, then it seems to detect the google-services.json file.

Comment: Yes! perfect thanks! This is the solution! Renaming my productFlavors from (for example) "NO" to "no" let me update com.google.gms:google-services to 4.3.3.

Answer (score 0):

Add this line at the bottom of your app build.gradle file and not at the top.

```
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

Comment: thanks, this line is at the end of my build.gradle already

Answer (score -1):

You need to get the configuration file from the developer's site and paste it in the app level directory of your project.
Generate file here developers.[google.com/mobile/add](https://firebase.google.com/)

Comment: Thanks for your help. I have my google-services.json but since the update from 4.2.0 to 4.3.0, locations are not recognized any more.

Comment: @RomainBarbier You can also put the file in app/src/{build_type} or app/src/{build_type}/{flavor_name}

Comment: @GabrieleMariotti Thanks for your help. As I said to Martin Zeitler, I looked to the documentation and trying app/src/{build_type}/{flavor_name} I still have the error. ERROR: File google-services.json is missing. The Google Services Plugin cannot function without it. 
 Searched Location: 
/my/project/app/google-services.json